# Why does my code print 2 different numbers? They're supposed to be the same

Tags: python, while-loop

The "seq" list won't have repeating numbers, and will never have a length longer than 9. I am trying to get my code to return the missing integer in a given list from 0-9. I resolved to do this by removing a number from an integer "checklist" every time the system finds a matching number. Somehow, the IF statement in line 7 manages to get called when it's technically false.

```
def get_missing_element(seq):
    missing = None
    i = 0
    f = 0
    checklist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    while f < len(checklist):
        if checklist[f] == seq[i]:
            checklist.remove(checklist[f])
            print("i see", seq[i])
            print("removed", checklist[f])
            i = i + 1
            f = 0
        f = f + 1
    return missing
seq = [1, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 9]
print(get_missing_element(seq))
```

I tried using For loops in the beginning, but I didn't know how to get a For loop to repeat itself without using a while loop. Does the root of my problem lie within the fact that I'm using a while loop here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a more general solution that doesn't rely on the elements being integers:

```
def get_missing_element(it):
    # {} without : makes a set
    checkset = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    for e in it:
        # This will throw if `e` is repeated or not in `checkset`.
        # Use `.discard(e)` to silently ignore such elements.
        checkset.remove(e)
    # tuple-unpacking will throw if there isn't exactly one element left.
    r, = checkset
    return r
seq = [1, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 9]
print(get_missing_element(seq))
```

Generally for questions of the form "is this a member", you want to use `set`, `dict`, or related (`frozenset`, `collections.Counter`, ...)

Comment: There's no need to remove items from a set. The symmetric difference is all you need

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for! Use a set instead of a list, perfect. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The issue in your code lies in the way you're modifying the checklist while iterating over it. When you remove an element from checklist, the indices of the remaining elements change. This can cause the loop to skip elements or behave unexpectedly. Additionally, the code does not handle the case where the number from seq is not found in checklist.

Instead of removing elements from checklist, you can use a simpler approach. Since seq contains unique numbers and its length is always less than or equal to 9, you can just find the sum of numbers from 0 to 9 and subtract the sum of elements in seq. The difference will be the missing number.

```
def get_missing_element(seq):
    total = sum(range(10))  # Sum of numbers from 0 to 9
    return total - sum(seq)  # The missing number is the difference

# Test the function
seq = [1, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 9]
print(get_missing_element(seq))
```

This approach is more efficient and avoids the complications of modifying a list while iterating over it.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I never thought of this approach! so much simpler...

Answer (score 1):

```
if checklist[f] == seq[i]:
    checklist.remove(checklist[f])
    print("i see", seq[i])
    print("removed", checklist[f])
```

Removing `checklist[f]` **changes the list**.  The next item in the list moves up to take its place.

So when you print `checklist[f]`, it is **a different item** than was present in the `if` statement.

You're printing a different item than the one that was removed.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that might be happening, but was unsure as to how it was happening. Thanks for clearing this up for me.